# jQuery Outputting Duplicate XML Child Nodes Incorrectly

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I'm using jQuery to parse and output XML. I have a nested loop to output all children of TASKS, but each iteration outputs all immediately children at once instead of one per line.

```
<xml version="1.0">
<choices>
    <choice id="1" name="Type 1">
        <description>
            Example a
        </description>
        <tasks>
            <task>Do this</task>
            <task>Do that</task>
        </tasks>
    </choice>
    <choice id="2" name="Type 2">
        <description>
            Example b
        </description>
        <tasks>
            <task>Do other</task>
            <task>Do something</task>
        </tasks>
    </choice>
</choices>
```

My script:

```
$(function(){
        "use strict";
//Above XML content is being passed as a string for this example
        var str = "<xml version='1.0'><choices><choice id=\"1\" name=\"Type 1\"><description>Example a</description><tasks><task>Do this</task><task>Do that</task></tasks></choice><choice id=\"2\" name=\"Type 2\"><description>Example b</description><tasks><task>Do other</task><task>Do something</task></tasks></choice></choices></xml>";
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(str);
        var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

        var temp = {};

        $xml.find('choice').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            temp.id = $this.attr('id');
            temp.title = $this.attr('name');
            temp.description = $this.find('description').text();
            temp.choices = [];

            var counter = 0;

            $this.find('tasks').eq( counter ).each(function(index, child) {

                document.write( $(child).find("task").text() + counter + "<br>");
                counter++;
            });


        });

    });
```

The output I want to see for children of tasks:

```
Do this0
Do that1
Do other2
Do something3
```

The output I am currently seeing:

```
Do thisDo that0
Do otherDo something0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is print the tasks, this can be simplified greatly to just this:

```
$xml.find('task').each(function (i) {
    document.write($(this).text() + i + "<br>");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhLSd/1/)

---

If you need the `choice` loop to do other things that you just left out of this question, you can change your task loop to this:

```
        $this.find('task').each(function() {

            document.write( $(this).text() + counter + "<br>");
            counter++;
        });
```

and move `counter` declaration above the `choice` loop

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhLSd/3/)
(check console in the jsfiddle, change `console.log` back to `document.write` in your actual code)

The above will loop through all the `task` tags within the current `choice` tag.

If you just want to look at the children of `tasks` regardless of the tag. You could do:

```
$this.find('tasks').children().each(function() { ...
```

If you want to make sure you are finding only `task` children of `tasks`, you could do this:

```
$this.find('tasks').children("task").each(function() {
```

All 3 of the above will have the same result with your current xml though (which is your expected result).

---

**The problem was** that you were finding "tasks" instead of each individual "task" in your `each()` loop and getting the text from all `task` tags within it. Instead, loop through each individual task.

To further break down what your original code was doing...

```
var counter = 0;
//find the first `tasks` element within `$this`, then loop through it (the single item first task)
$this.find('tasks').eq( counter ).each(function(index, child) {
            //find all the text within all the `task` tags. put 0 and a <br> after
            document.write( $(child).find("task").text() + counter + "<br>");
            //increment counter, doesn't matter since this block of code will only be ran once
            counter++;
        });
```

Comment: The brilliance is in the simplicity of your answer. I apparently am a fan of Rube Goldberg.

Comment: Also, if this is all you need it to do.. there is a lot of unnecessary stuff. You could just get rid of the `choice` loop and just do `$xml.find('task').each(function(i) { document.write($(this).text()+i+"<br>")});`, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/fhLSd/1/

Comment: What I'm doing is a bit more complex, but I am outputting each logical step I make since this eventually going to be an array within an objet within an array. I appreciate all the possible ways to output.